# Как расставить знаки препинания в данном тексте?

Tags: пунктуация

> В те годы марксисты всего мира одобряли деятельность Салот Сара, строителя «научного социализма». Кстати, Пол Пот – это сокращение от французского «politique potentielle», или «перспективный политик». Перспективы действительно были большие – Пол Пот обещал построить социализм за четыре года – без денег, без городов, без профессоров, без техники. Только за счет «организационного плана».

1) Нужно обособлять "действительно" в этом контексте?
2) Нужно ли здесь брать в кавычки слово, написанное латиницей?
3) Как лучше расставить знаки в предпоследнем предложении (может, где-то двоеточие вместо тире)?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Перспективы действительно были большие...**
   Я думаю, что в этом предложении слово *действительно* является наречием и не требует выделения запятыми: это член предложения в значении ***на самом деле, подлинно, в реальности.***
   (Обычно вводное слово *действительно* служит для подтверждения ранее высказанного утверждения, а наречие *действительно* — для акцентирования выражения, ранее не обозначенного.)

[Действительно](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dmitriev/951)

2. Кстати, Пол Пот — это сокращение от французского «politique potentielle»...
   Такое оформление вполне допустимо.

Но я бы написала так (с оформлением *курсивом* слов другого языка):
Кстати, Пол Пот — это сокращение от французского *politique potentielle*…

[Конгломерат](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82) (лат. *conglomeratus* — «скученный, уплотнённый»)…

3. **Перспективы действительно были большие** [какие именно]**: Пол Пот обещал построить социализм за четыре года** [тире для акцента на том, каким образом] **— без денег, без городов, без профессоров, без техники.**
   В этом предложении первое тире, думаю, нужно заменить двоеточием.